# What exactly does the tf reader returns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

the tf reader usually returns keys and values, so what are they?
I'm trying to see what exactly they are, but failed.
while running this:

```
filename = tf.train.string_input_producer(['/home/noodle/99282.jpg'])
reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
key, k = reader.read(filename)
g = tf.image.decode_image(k)
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
    sess.run(g)
    sess.run(key)
    print(key, g)
    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

it returns

```
Tensor("ReaderReadV2:0", shape=(), dtype=string) Tensor("decode_image_1/cond_jpeg/Merge:0", dtype=uint8)
```

Can't figure out~~~

Comment: Key is filename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example `key` is the filename and `k` is the jpeg encoded image. When you use `sess.run(key)` the tensor `key` is evaluated and the result returned as a python variable. You can read more about this [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session) in the `run` section. For your example:

```
py_g, py_key = sess.run([g, key)
print(py_key)
plt.imshow(py_g)
plt.show()
```

Note that you should call `sess.run` with a list of all of the tensors you want to evaluate to ensure that all variables are in sync. If you evaluate the tensors separately they will correspond to separate graph executions and could get out of sync if fed by queues (e.g. `string_input_producer` had a list of multiple filenames).

Comment: Glad to help. Please accept my answer when you get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from the docs of `tf.WholeFileReader`:

> A Reader that outputs the entire contents of a file as a value.
>   To use, enqueue filenames in a Queue.  The output of `Read` will
>   be a *filename (key)* and the *contents of that file (value)*.

But, I guess you're doing it wrong while decoding the image by not specifying the number of channels for the image to decode.

```
tf.image.decode_image(contents, channels=None, name=None)
```

And please don't `print()` the decoded image. Try to show it using some plotting library like matplotlib.